# How do I convert a Map of <String, List<Object>> into a Map of <Object, List<String>>?

Tags: java, list, sorting, dictionary

### Problem description

I have an old Java-programming textbook which I'm going through, and I've got stuck on a problem.

I need to convert this:

```
Map<String, List<Clock>> timeTableSortedByDestination = 
    new HashMap<String, List<Clock>>();
```

Into this:

```
Map<Clock, List<String>> timeTableSortedByDepartTime = 
    new HashMap<Clock, List<String>>();
```

In one method:

```
static Map<Clock, List<String>> flipMap(Map<String, List<Clock>> originalMap) {
    // implementation
}
```

I'm thinking of going through the original Map with loops and if's, but is there a smoother or simpler way to work through it? The book deals only in "source-code" Java (no Javascript).

### Answer Update

Okay, so I went with James Grammatikos suggestion, works perfect. Here's what I wrote:

```
static Map<Clock, List<String>> flipMap(Map<String, List<Clock>> originalMap) {

    Map<Clock, List<String>> newMap = new HashMap<Clock, List<String>>();

    for(String s : originalMap.keySet()) {
       for(Clock c : originalMap.get(s)) {
           newMap.put(c, new ArrayList<String>());
           }
       }

    for(Clock c : newMap.keySet()) {
        for(String s : originalMap.keySet()) {

            if(originalMap.get(s).contains(c)) {
                List<String> temp = newMap.get(c);
                temp.add(s);

                newMap.put(c, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    return newMap;
}
```

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Java is to Javascript as car is to carpet.

Comment: You should change the variable names: a hash map does not maintain an order, sorted or otherwise. As to your question, no, there's no simpler way.

Comment: "I'm thinking of going through the original Map with loops" yeay! " and if's" hu? Try it.

Comment: Okay, well I was afraid of that. Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: It sounds like you can solve the problem on your own. Once you're done, you should post your answer so others can find it later! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through all the clocks, build a new map with the clocks as keys, then iterate through the original map again. I replaced clocks with objects here because i was too lazy to define a clock class

```
Map<String,List<Object>> timeTableSortedByDestination = new HashMap<String,List<Object>>();
Map<Object,List<String>> timeTableSortedByDepartTime = new HashMap<Object,List<String>>();
List<String> temp;    

// dump all of the objects into the new map
for(String s : timeTableSortedByDestination.keySet()){
    for(Object o : timeTableSortedByDestination.get(s)){
        timeTableSortedByDepartTime.put(o, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
}

//iterating through each list in the original map
for(Object o : timeTableSortedByDepartTime.keySet()){
    for(String s : timeTableSortedByDestination.keySet()){
        // if the object was in that list
        if(timeTableSortedByDestination.get(s).contains(o)){
            temp = timeTableSortedByDepartTime.get(o);
            temp.add(s);
            // add the corresponding string to the list in the new map
            timeTableSortedByDepartTime.put(o, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, spot on. Though I wonder, what have you declared `temp` as? Is that a new list or map-entry?

Comment: No worries, figured it was a `List<String>` ;-)

Comment: Sorry, didn't end up copying in those definitions by accident. Just edited it to clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to group a List to a Map.  You haven't provided enough detail to solve your particular problem.  Here's a generic utility method:

```
public interface GroupingExpression<T, U> {
    T groupBy(U item);
}

public static <T, U> Map<T, List<U>> group(List<U> list, GroupingExpression<T, U> groupingExpression) {

    Map<T, List<U>> groupedMap = new LinkedHashMap<T, List<U>>();

    for(U item : list) {

        T key = groupingExpression.groupBy(item);

        List<U> keyedList = groupedMap.get(key);

        if(keyedList == null) {
            keyedList = new ArrayList<U>();
            groupedMap.put(key, keyedList);
        }

        keyedList.add(item);
    }

    return groupedMap;
}
```